# Java JTable not showing up

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to show the data into the Jtable, my AbstractTableModel class works fine and the table works in another gui but in this case is not working at all. I put the JTable inside the scrollPane but still does not work

```
public Eliminar_Cliente() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 452, 223);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    setContentPane(contentPane);


    JLabel lblEscribaElId = new JLabel("Escriba el ID del Usuario");
    lblEscribaElId.setBounds(150, 11, 115, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblEscribaElId);

    Search_Field = new JTextField();
    Search_Field.setBounds(150, 36, 115, 20);
    contentPane.add(Search_Field);
    Search_Field.setColumns(10);

    JButton Eliminar = new JButton("Eliminar");
    Eliminar.setBounds(97, 137, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(Eliminar);

    JButton Cancelar = new JButton("Cancelar");
    Cancelar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            dispose();
        }
    });
    Cancelar.setBounds(235, 137, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(Cancelar, BorderLayout.EAST);

    Search_Button = new JButton("Buscar");
    Search_Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


            try {
                String ID = Search_Field.getText();
                List<Getters> list = null;
                if(ID != null && ID.trim().length() > 0)
                {

                    list = MA.searchClientID(ID);
                    TableCol model = new TableCol(list);
                    table.setModel(model);
                }
                else
                {
                    ERROR_GUI ER =new ERROR_GUI();
                    ER.setVisible(true);
                }

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    Search_Button.setBounds(275, 35, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(Search_Button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(429, 67, -425, 14);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);

    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
}
```

when i click the button for testing all the information displayed in the console so it seems that it works but i am unable to display it in the JTable.

Comment: why do you have your code in the constructor?

Comment: May be `scrollPane.setBounds(429, 67, -425, 14);` is the source of your problems. Width of a component shouldn't be less than 0 (if you want to see this component)..

Comment: 1) Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. then you won't have problems like the one explained by Sergiy. 2) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: Thanks guys, it was actually the null in the layout, i am using now the group layout and everything goes pretty well :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is referring to current Jframe

```
this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
this.pack();
this.setVisible(true);
```